# Need help with a Fourier Transform Question

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, hyperbolic-functions

I need an way to solve this Fourier transform problem.
$$
f(t)= 
\begin{cases}
\cosh(t)  &   \text{ For } |t|<1\\
0         &   \text{ For }|t|>1
\end{cases}
$$
The given answer for the problem is given as

[image: Given answer]

This is what I have got so far. I can't find a way to progress any further toward that answer.

[image: First steps]

I realize I can create a $\sinh$ or a $\sin/\cos$ function from what I have. I have tried, but it does not get the given answer.

I would appreciate any help with this. I have a few Fourier Transform sums for my assignment and this is supposedly the easiest :(

Comment: Please try to write the math formulas, we use Latex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there

$$F(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-1}^1 (e^t+ e^{-t}) e^{-j \omega t}dt$$

But

$$ \frac{1}{1-j\omega}(e  e^{-j\omega}-e^{-1} e^{j\omega})+\frac{1}{1+j\omega}(e  e^{j\omega}-e^{-1} e^{-j\omega})=$$

$$= \frac{1}{e}\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}[(1+j\omega) (e^2 e^{-j\omega} - e^{j\omega})+(1-j\omega) (e^2 e^{j\omega} - e^{-j\omega})]=$$

$$=\frac{1}{e}\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}[ (e^2-1)2 \cos(\omega) +  (e^2+1)2 \omega\sin(\omega)] $$

(there might be some error with the signs, this needs revising, but you get the idea)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to all of this and I really don't know how to use Latex. Someone seems to have edited my post and fixed it though. Thanks so much for your help. I followed this method and I got really really close, but I end up with this:

http://postimg.org/image/9sppe7qfr/

I have no idea how to get the omega over to the sin term and get rid of the j's. :(

Comment: Check your signs. Unless I'm mistaken, the terms with a difference in the exponentials $(e^{jw}-e^{-jw})$ is the one which should have the factor $jw$

Comment: BTW, it's quite easy (and _very_ useful) to learn the basics of Latex, start here http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thanks for the link. Appreciated :) I'll check once again, but I think the signs all fine. The only difference I could see is that in your second step you have taken $ + 1/(1 + j*\omega) $ instead of $ -1/(1 + j*\omega) $ as the second coefficient

Comment: Can't seem to find where I went wrong :(

Comment: I'm too busy now to check everything, but never understimate the possibility that the wrong ones are the others :-)

Comment: I'll keep working on it. Thanks loads anyways :) If you're free sometime could you take a look at this too? http://postimg.org/image/eko9csv7l/ I'm supposed to find the Fourier Transform of this and I'm kinda lost. The only way I can imagine going about it is by considering it as a 6-part piecewise function, but that seems really really really long and complicated :S Thanks so much again for your help with this sum :)

Comment: Write your function as the sum of a triangle (-3,3), a rectangle (-2,2) and another rectangle (-1,1).

Comment: As in consider it as the sum of two rectangles and three squares and then use the linearity property of the Fourier transform to add them together? Forgive the incessant questioning. I'm a first year undergrad student and the assignments are way over what we learn in class :(. Wouldn't the resulting waveform have vertical lines between the segments instead of discontinuities then in the graph? I plotted this in MATLAB http://postimg.org/image/r7hlh8aqd/

Comment: No problem, but this is not really the place to get this kind of 'chat' help. A function graph can never have vertical lines (http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/relation/vertical-line-test.php).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. This one has me stumped. I'll post another question about it. Thanks for everything :)